# Select not Selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 4 dropdowns on it. The default selected option in all the dropdowns is "Please Select". I want to use Jquery to make sure all dropdowns have a value before the page is submitted, but my code only works on the first one. Does anyone have a way that I can check all of the dropdowns at once?

```
function doconfirm() {
  if ($('select').val() == '') {
    alert("Please Select All Fields");
   }  
}
```

I'm sure I am missing something but I cant figure it out.
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that since it is not a function that it only works on the first select on the page?????

Comment: It's because .val() command only returns the value of the first element in the wrapped set (jQuery object). Hence need to check the value on each element in the wrapped set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function doconfirm() {
  if ($('select').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
         alert("Please Select All Fields");
         return(false);
    }  
  });
}
```

Comment: And make sure that your html is correct -- <option value="">Please Select</option> and <option>Please Select</option> will return different things with val(). The first is an empty string, the second returns "Please Select"

Answer (score 4):

A slight variation on @mgroves' approach, this *explicitly* tests for at least one selected option, and alerts on the first select that doesn't have one. If there is any advantage to this approach, it is better readability (especially since the use of .val() is somewhat ambiguous for this purpose):

```
function doconfirm() {
  if($('select').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).find('option:selected').length) {
         alert("Please Select All Fields");
         return(false);
    }  
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for a different take on this why not use

```
function doConfirm() {

    var toReturn = true;

    if ( $('select').filter( function(){
            return $(this).val() === ''; 
         }).length ) {

        toReturn = false;
        //notify user

    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').each(function(s){if(!this.val())...});
```